# Maven Security Concerns

Tags: security, ant, maven, build-tools

Are there security concerns with using Maven?  I use Ant today for my main project, but I do use Maven for my "samples" project where I write program spikes.  I do like some parts of Maven, but have a concern with downloading my jars through the tool.  Is this an unfounded concern?  How secure is "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"?  Is there a more secure way of using the tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty secure and standard. If ever the security of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ is compromised, there will have big repercussion in Java devs. I never heard that this site is hacked.

That said, you are not bounded by default repository. You can configure your own repository using [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php) and install *safe* artifacts manually to them. You may also block remote repositories using Nexus/Artifactory setting. Although, I never needed to do this. But look [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-manage-repo.html), perhaps it's possible.

Please note that you will have to block your local repository to use "repo1", else the local repository will download artifacts from there by default.

*Edit 1*: added missing link

Comment: Sony also had pretty huge confidence in the safety of its websites for many years until 2011...