# Security of outdated maven artifacts

Tags: java, maven, security

Maven allows developers to have their artifacts depend on ancient artifacts as old as 10 years (e.g. commons-el:commons-el:1.0 released in 2005, or jetty:javax.servlet:5.1.11 released in 2007).  It seems a common practice in the java ecosystem to depend on specific old-versioned artifacts  because their updates often break API silently.

Are those old artifacts patched if a security flaw is found?  Who is going to take care of this?

If I pull in, say the newest release of [spark](http://spark.apache.org) org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.0.0, after maven downloading 3GiB of its dependencies, I can see a couple of them even older than 2005. If the resulting spark is executed, will those outdated dependencies expose patential security flaws?

Note: this is neither about [security of java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_security) itself, nor [security of maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013792/maven-security-concerns), but artifacts delivered by maven.

Comment: Note in particular that many of the "outdated" packages (such as your `javax.servlet`) are in fact API packages, where the underlying implementation may be very recent.

Comment: @chrylis, thanks for pointing that out.  I was using some 10-year-old extreme examples to prove my point.  If we look for 5-year-old ones, there are more outdated (meaning: many more new versions available) non-trival artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

Maven's central repository [requirements](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html) do not speak to transitive dependency security issues.

The responsibility for updating transitive dependencies is reliant on the owner of the dependency. The owner/maintainer of the dependency would need to implement any fixes to issues caused in their codebase when updating their dependencies(the ones with the security flaws).

As a user of dependencies in your application that may have insecure transitive dependencies,  you have a few options:

- Update to the latest version of the dependency, the dependency owner may have already implemented a fix.
- Exclude insecure transitive dependencies. Use at your own risk, as this may have unintended effects. Often this does work, as the insecure dependency may not actually be used by the dependency you needed.
- Fork the dependency codebase, update the insecure transitive dependency, fix any issues, and submit a pull request.

Also, if you want a detailed report on the security of dependencies in your java application, you can check out the [OWASP Dependency Checker](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check), which checks your project's dependencies(including transitive) against the NIST NVD database.

Comment: I recently used the OWASP dependency checker but I got the impression that the deserialization vulnerability (see for example [NotSoSerial](https://github.com/kantega/notsoserial)) is not covered. Do you happen to know if that is true? It looks like you can use FindBugs to [check on the vulnerability](http://blog.h3xstream.com/2016/01/deserialization-vulnerability.html) though.

Comment: Dependency checker checks against the NIST National Vulnerability Database. Flaws within dependencies need to be reported to the NVD to be included in the dependency checker report. Here is what they have for [deserialization](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=deserialization&search_type=all&cves=on). Deserialization is also defined within the [CWE](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/502.html), which they use to define vulnerabilities.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If security flaws are discovered in a particular package, the expectation is that a new patched version is published by the authors. To your point the older vulnerable version remains in Maven Central and at first glance this would appear to be a very bad thing.

It leads to the following obvious questions:

- Why doesn't someone patch these vulnerable versions?
- Why doesn't someone remove these vulnerable versions?

Let's explore the consequences....

If someone is changing a library version that I'm using, how certain am I that the code remains **functionally** the same? This is why patches are handled as new versions. It's a lot less work for the author.

So if old vulnerable versions are not being patched, surely they should be deleted? Well... If users don't want to be use the latest patched version of a library, for fear it would break their code, they would certainly be just as unhappy if someone removed the library version they did depend on..... Damned if you do, and damned if you don't....

So in conclusion it's a case of user beware. We all need to manage our dependencies and adapt to changes in the various underlying APIs. If we ignore change, we run the risk of exposure to a vulnerability without an option to upgrade. Welcome to software development :-)

Comment: Thanks, your comments let me realize maven cannot replace the package managers of GNU/Linux and UNIX distributions, where security teams look after all the packages as a whole.  Maven is more decentralized.

Comment: Indeed. However they have two different use cases. Maven is used to build the software that is then subsequently packaged for distribution on your chosen OS. So you're correct it's the package maintainers that do the worthy work that keeps you secure.